# Custom SharePoint 2010 Documentset contenttype

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type

I'm working on a custom contenttype of the type Documentset.
I want to set the alllowed contenttypes, but this is not working, it's only showing the defeult document. I read several blogs but i can't find my solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Document Set (0x0120D520) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0120D520008d2ff418027e4c31b54d155b98596748"
               Overwrite="True"
               Name="Custom Dossier"
               Group="Custom group"
               Description="Custom dossier"
               Inherits="True"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{8D6C094C-3E1F-41f4-BEE3-25B27EE09702}" Name="Dossier_Nummer" DisplayName="Dossiernummer" Required="True"  />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes">
        <act:AllowedContentTypes xmlns:act="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes" LastModified="05/31/2012 08:46:56">
          <AllowedContentType id="0x0101" />
          <AllowedContentType id="0x0101000490d50c50624b6ca21c637ef39cd89b" />
        </act:AllowedContentTypes>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContentType binding element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543598) for assigning CTs to document library.

Comment: I'm only defining the CT's. There's not an libary at the moment, so i can't bind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding all the nodes necessary for the document set template? A great example is located here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Create-Custom-Document-Set-318393ce/sourcecode?fileId=57420&pathId=1173424883